# XSLT Function insert-before not recognized

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm creating a xslt file with baseX but the function insert-before is not recognized. It is a standard function (you can see it here http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp) and I also tried to declare the namespace fn like this

```
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
```

and then call the function with fn:insert-before but it still doesn't work. This is a sample of my code

```
<xsl:call-template name="temp">
   ....
   <xsl:with-param name="array" select="fn:insert-before($array,$count+1,$succ)"/>
   ...
</xsl:call-template>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be that you are trying to run this Xslt 2.0 function on a Xslt 1.0 processor?

Comment: I am not familiar with baseX and its XSLT 2.0 support. Are you able to use other XSLT/XPath 2.0 functionality without problems with baseX?

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  It looks mighty suspicious that you're using `array` as both a param name and as an argument in a single line. What does the template calling this one look like?

Comment: I can use other XSLT/XPath 2.0 functionality with BaseX but I have problems with every XSLT 2.0 function. When I say it doesn't work I mean that I get an error message saying that it's not possible to compile the stylesheet. My whole code works on altova xml spy but not on baseX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The BaseX documentation at

http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XSLT_Module

states that it uses the default JDK 1.5 XSLT engine by default. This only supports XSLT 1.0. The same page explains how to configure it to run with an XSLT 2.0 engine such as Saxon.